# Heroku: There was an issue setting up your app environment. Name is invalid

Tags: heroku

When I try to use this app.json:

```
{
    "stack": "heroku-18",
    "repository": "https://github.com/OpenHumans/oh-data-source-template",
    "logo": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/3341265?s=280&v=4",
    "scripts": {
        "postdeploy": "python manage.py init_proj_config"
    },
    "env": {
      "SECRET_KEY": {
        "description": "This is set for you and is used to encrypt data.",
        "generator": "secret"
      },
      "OH_CLIENT_ID": {
        "description": "See http://openhumans.org/direct-sharing/projects/manage",
        "value": ""
      },
      "OH_CLIENT_SECRET": {
        "description": "See http://openhumans.org/direct-sharing/projects/manage",
        "value": ""
      },
      "OH_ACTIVITY_PAGE": {
        "description": "See http://openhumans.org/direct-sharing/projects/manage",
        "value": ""
      },
      "APP_BASE_URL ": {
        "description": "e.g. https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com - no trailing slash!",
        "value": "https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com"
      },
      "DEBUG": {
        "description": "Displays detailed error info for web requests.  Set False in production.",
        "value": "false"
      },
      "HEROKU_APP": {
        "description": "If true, ALLOWED_HOSTS is set to all.",
        "value": "true"
      }
    },
    "addons": [
        "coralogix:free-30mbday",
        "heroku-redis:hobby-dev",
        {
            "plan": "heroku-postgresql",
            "options": {
                "version": "9.5"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

to deploy from:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmikepsinn%2Foh-quantimodo-source

I get the error no matter what I set the name to:

[image]

I've tried adding the optional name field to the app.json but that doesn't help either.